# Select all elements on document except div elements & apply css to them

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to select all elements on the page except 'div' elements and one by one apply a class to them for 5 seconds. This is my jQuery code:

```
$('*').not('div').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("flash");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("flash");
    }, 5000);
});
```

After searching, I think this code is good but my app doesn't even start. It appears right after launching a circle loading and doesn't start. Any help?

**EDIT:**
After the page is loaded, I want each element (except div) to have the class flash for 5 secs, one by one. Sorry I didn't explain this earlier

Comment: I'd suggest you do this in CSS alone. It should be easily possible, depending on the effects the `flash` class uses. Using the wildcard selector to affect almost every element in the DOM will be pretty damn slow.

Comment: the thing is this will be triggered if a condition is true on the page loading. And my pages don't have many elements aside from div elements

Comment: In that case add a class to a parent element on load if that condition hits and hook the CSS rules to that. Using the wildcard selector should be considered a last resort

Comment: So all elements are having the `flash` class and disappear after 5 seconds after loading? And you want this effect to be done one by one, at an interval of 5 seconds?

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy yes that's it. one by one, 5 sec's each, except div elements

Comment: Please answer the first question.  Otherwise I cannot give you an answer

Comment: To all elements(except div) i want to add flash class after the page is loaded but one by one, 5 secs each.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy I think the interval is not mentioned by OP. he just means to have the class to each element for 5 seconds.

Comment: @TiagoPina check my answer it may help you...

Comment: Question guys, if i have a button inside a div, with your code it will run the code on the button or because of it being inside the div it won't be affected?

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy if can check my question above i would be appreciate it ;)

Comment: @JayeshChitroda if can check my question above i would be appreciate it ;)

Comment: @TiagoPina I think the button will be affected. Why not try in your code and check?

Answer (score 2):

Using `$('body > *').not("div")` you can get all elements except div.

```js
$('body > *').not("div").each(function(i) { // it will loop through all elements except div
  var obj = $(this); // get current element
  setTimeout(function() {
     $(obj).addClass("flash"); // add class
  }, i*500); // delay 200 ms
  setTimeout(function() {
      $(obj).removeClass("flash"); // remove class after some delay
  }, i*1000); // delay 500 ms
});
```

```css
.flash {
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul>
      <li> AAA </li>
      <li> bbb </li>
      <li> ddd </li>
      <li> ccc </li>
    </ul>
    <span>This is Span</span>
    <div>This is Div</div>
    <span>This is Span</span> <br />
    <label>This is Label</label>
    <div id = "tags">
      <div id = "1">
        aaa
      </div>
      <div id = "2">
        bbb
      </div>
      <div id = "3">
       ccc
      </div>
      <div id = "4">
       ddd
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li> 111 </li>
      <li> 222 </li>
      <li> 333 </li>
      <li> 444 </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood OP's meaning. OP wants to do the add and remove action ONE BY ONE, instead of doing them all at once.

Comment: the code seams perfect for what i want, I'm still trying to run it, just had a pause. but why is $('body > *') body necessary? just '*' isn't enough?

Comment: yes otherwise it will check all tags like script, meta tag, head, title.. we dont need to check that all thats why..it will only find elements inside bidy but not div

Comment: @JayeshChitroda Already manged to put the code working, thx mate. but the thing is i want that the next element to have the flash class just start when the one before as ended and with your code there are elements that run the class and the one before still has it. tried to change the delay but still the same. any clue how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong.

Hope that I understand your question well. You want, let's say, the first non-div element to show for 5 seconds, and after that the first to remove class and the second non-div element to show for 5 seconds, and so on.

You are using each function. Each function will **ALL** be executed *at once*, regardless of the number of satisfying elements. You should instead do something like this:

```
var c=0;
function action(){
  $('body *').not('div').eq(c).addClass("flash");
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('body *').not('div').eq(c).removeClass("flash");
    c++;
    if(c<$('body *').not('div').length)action();
  },5000);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  action();
});
```

If you are running them one by one, always use `function` to help you. Stop the function by using a variable to control it. That always help.

**NOTE**: This code *MAY NOT WORK* if the elements which are not divs are nested. But I think all elements which are not divs will def be applicable.

Comment: gonna try it, just had a pause on the moment. i'll feedback in a moment. thx mate

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting so many timeouts why not just do one:

```js
var elements = $('*').not('div');
elements.each(function() { $(this).addClass('flash'); })
setTimeout(function() {
    elements.each(function() { $(this).removeClass('flash'); })
}, 5000);
```

```css
div,
span {display:inline-block; width:50px; height:50px; background:green;}
.flash {background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<div></div>
```

If you want a visible delay in between adding the classes for each item then you will need to add a delay but again, this will add a lot of timeouts which could cause your page to crash if you have loads of elements on it

```js
var animationRunning = false,
  elements = $('*').not('div'),
  endIndex = elements.length - 1,
  delayTime = 250;

$('#button').click(function() {
  if (!animationRunning) { // stops multiple clicks happening
    animationRunning = true;
    elements.each(function(index) {
      var element = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        element.addClass('flash');
      }, delayTime * index);
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
      elements.each(function(index) {
        var element = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
          element.removeClass('flash');
          if (index == endIndex) {
            animationRunning = false;
          }
        }, delayTime * index);
      })
    }, 5000 + (elements.length * delayTime)); // this will start the unflash animation 5 esconds after the last flash class is added
  }
});
```

```css
div,
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
.flash {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<div></div>

<button id="button">start animation</button>
```

Comment: @PradeepPansari this answer also doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: @Pete i guess you missed the one by one.

Comment: @Jai edited to do it one by one.  Of course .each would run pretty fast so the difference in adding one by one and applying to all elements at the same time will be negligable

Comment: @PradeepPansari, sorry, didn't see your answer as it had been blurred out

Comment: thx for the reply @Pete . but if i have a button inside a div the code will run anyway on the button?

Comment: @TiagoPina, updated second snippet to show button click animation

Comment: but if that button is inside a div, like:
 <div> <button id="button">start animation</button> </div>
the code will run on the button or because being inside the div it won't?

Comment: @TiagoPina Being in a div won't make any difference - you are adding a class to all elements that are not a div so the button is not a div so it will be styled

Comment: @Pete add your code to my app, just changed when the code is triggered (not when a button is clicked but when a condition is true) and it doesn't flash the elements one by one, instead flash them all together

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
$(function(){
   $("body :not('div')").each(function(index){       
     // add the class
     setTimeout(function(){
       $(this).addClass("flash");
     }.bind(this),index*5000);
     // remove the class
     setTimeout(function(){
       $(this).removeClass("flash");
     }.bind(this),(index+1)*5000); 
   });     
});
```

Comment: Read the question carefully and you will consider deleting this answer

Comment: @fareednamrouti thanks for your reply. your code it's working but in some pages the first element to flash take +/- 15secs and i want the first element to flash right after the page's loaded. and why you use bind? and for last, why this part of code: "index*5000", already some other replies had it and still can't understand.

Comment: First: this code will run after the page completely loaded but you should consider that this code include all elements even invisible elements such as script, style even comments elements and also nested elements. You can use :visible pseudo selector, but Honestly I think better for you to use specific html  class to decide witch elements to flash

Comment: 2nd point: function.bind has a magical use where you can change the (this) inside the function and even pass extra parameters to be added to the function when it calls, for example you can do:

Comment: var myAlert = window.alert.bind(window,"hello"); now if you call myAlert() this will call window.alert("hello"); you can read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: 3rd point: when you use .each you will have a loop for all selected elements where (this) is the html element and the index parameter is element  index starting from 0 to elements.length-1, and what setTimeout basically do is to run a function (first parameter) after a specific number of  milliseconds (2nd parameter), so we tell setTimeout to wait (index*5000 milliseconds) so for 1st element = 0*5 seconds => 0 seconds and for the 2nd  = 1*5 seconds => 5 seconds and so on

Comment: To avoid hidden elements you can do $("body :not('div')").is(":visible").each ....